# django manager get any one object

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models, one-to-many

In a many-one model, I want to get only one of the objects(any one object) from the manager, how to do that?

```
models.School.student_set.any_one()
```

I did not find any such method in the documentation. right now I am doing something like:

```
models.School.student_set.all()[0]
```

which I believe to be inefficient.

Comment: No it wouldn't since it would issue `SELECT * FROM LIMIT 1` or something like that depending on database you use. [Read more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QuerySets are not evaluated until you actually get some data from them, so slicing the result of `all()` is actually going to be efficient.

See [docs on QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) - "No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.". Also documenation on [limiting QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) mentions your case explicitly.

If you feel adventurous, you can verify it yourself by looking at `django.db.connection.queries` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running))